# Accessing cli global files with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I'm developing a CLI module that can be installed either locally or globally. It references local templates to be used during the CLI process (e.g. copy some of them in the current folder, ...).

How can I retrieve the path where those templates are installed (in the current `node_modules` folder or in the global npm/yarn `node_modules` folder) to use them?

Comment: I don't have clear what exactly you want. Those local templates are created at runtime by your cli? or do exist in your project?

Comment: They are part of the project and store with the binaries

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion around [yarn] and [yarnpkg].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's the best solution but I manage to retrieve the binary path by doing : `path.resolve(require.resolve('my-cli'), '../', 'templates')`

Source: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/388#issuecomment-264731257

Answer (score 0):

So the scenario is that a user installs your tool via `npm install`, and then that tool copy some templates -- from your project folder -- into the user current working directory (among other things).

So your template files may be installed in a local `node_modules` installation or in the global one.

In both cases, you can access the absolute path to a resource given a relative path from your script file, [via the path module](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html):

```
const pathToResource = path.resolve('../templates/myTemplate.txt');
```

`pathToResource` will be the absolute path and will change from some users to others, depending upon they installed the module locally or globally.

Comment: `resolve` returns the absolute path of the working directory, not the path where the binaries are installed. Am I missing something?